# How should I create a rounded layout in android in which that the contents below it draws over the corners?

Tags: android

I know how to make a rounded layout if the background is the same color as the layout, but I am trying to make it so the background is green, but the layout is grey so then the corners stick out and I can't seem to find a solution. Here is the code...

**The drawable shape**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
<corners android:radius="10dip"/>
<padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

**The layout I use it in as a background**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/popupwindow">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:textSize="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: How the corners look like(this happens on the top also)]

The corners look like this on the top as well... what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you need to make two layouts.. One for the green background only which will be your topmost layout and the next one for the rounded corner shape which will hold your contents :)

Answer (score 0):

First change the stroke color to green color that you want and that would be -

```
<stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#62f441" />
```

Second is that the background of the parent view is visible so to hide that -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/popupwindow">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:textSize="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This should work but for some reason when I call the background transparent it just turns white

Comment: In the above layout it will show you the white color but when you'll include it in another layout with `#62f441` background color then I'll act as a transparent layer.

Answer (score 0):

Use CardView widget for this purpose.It is more effective and easy to use.

https://developer.android.com/samples/CardView/index.html
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html